# decision tree--'str' object has no attribute 'keys'--Python3.6

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, key, decision-tree

I'm trying to get the depth of a tree.
The following is my code:

```
def getTreeDepth(myTree):
    maxDepth = 0
    firstStr = list(myTree.keys())[0]
    secondDict = myTree[firstStr]
    for key in list(secondDict.keys()):
        if type(secondDict[key]).__name__ == 'dict':
            thisDepth = 1+ getTreeDepth(secondDict)
        else:
            thisDepth = 1
        if thisDepth > maxDepth: maxDepth = thisDepth

    return maxDepth
```

However, when I run it:

```
myTree = {'no surfacing': {0: 'no', 1: {'flippers': {0: 'no', 1: 'yes'}}}}
getTreeDepth(myTree)


<ipython-input-54-d4442919fa4f> in getTreeDepth(myTree)
     17     firstStr = list(myTree.keys())[0]
     18     secondDict = myTree[firstStr]
---> 19     for key in list(secondDict.keys()):
     20         if type(secondDict[key]).__name__ == 'dict':
     21             thisDepth = 1+ getTreeDepth(secondDict)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How do I correct it without change of this algorithm?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
myTree = {
    'no surfacing': { 
        0: 'no', 
        1: {
            'flippers': {
                0: 'no', 
                1: 'yes'}}}}
```

> ```
> def myTreeDepth(myTree):
>     maxDepth = 0
>     for value in myTree.values():
>         if type(value) == type({}): 
>             thisDepth = 1 + myTreeDepth(value)
>         else:
>             thisDepth = 1
>         if thisDepth > maxDepth: 
>             maxDepth = thisDepth
>     return maxDepth
> print('maxDepth =', getTreeDepth(myTree))
> ```

gives:

```
maxDepth = 4
```

NOTES:

1. The `.keys()` method of a dictionary returns an iterable so there is no need to convert the returned value to a list in order to iterate over it. The same is valid for `.values()` and `.items()`
2. The iteration checking the depth of a dictionary tree runs over dictionary `.values()` and not `.keys()`. And if you want to work with the entire dictionary entry you can iterate using `for key, value in dict.items()`
3. There is no need for `firstStr = list(myTree.keys())[0]` and `secondDict = myTree[firstStr]` in the algorithm you are using.